# Scala.js matchers with facades types

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala.js

I cannot get basic tests using matchers working with Scala.js with Three.js facade. Following code prints error "scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray__Z' of null".

```
import org.denigma.threejs.Vector3
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class TestVector extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "Vector" should "work" in {
    val v000 = new Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    v000 should be (v000)
  }
}
```

Complete project shared at [GitHub](https://github.com/OndrejSpanel/JSTest).

I guess it must be something related to facaded native types, as tests with classes defined in Scala work fine.

I did not find any gotchas documented regarding Scala.js and matchers. Am I missing something obvious?

Complete stack trace of the error:

```
[info] - should work *** FAILED ***
[info]   scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray__Z' of null
[info]   at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.isArrayClass(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:19470:14)
[info]   at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.isArray(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:19461:32)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Assertions$.areEqualComparingArraysStructurally(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:30299:29)
[info]   at org.scalatest.words.BeWord$$anon$15.apply(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:26853:49)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Matchers$ShouldMethodHelper$.shouldMatcher(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:8592:29)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Matchers$AnyShouldWrapper.should(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:8523:115)
[info]   at {anonymous}()(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:54138:20)
[info]   at scala.scalajs.runtime.AnonFunction0.apply(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:29505:23)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:2911:7)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(W:\Test\JSTest\target\scala-2.11\jstest-test-fastopt.js:37772:10)
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Added. I have also checked basic Scala classes work fine for me, it is only Three.js facaded types which fail.

Comment: This is a known Scala.js bug [#2712](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2712) that should be fixed in the next version. I don't have time right now to figure out a workaround.